# How can I use CGAffineTransform to skew a UIView in multiple directions, for example make one side larger than the other?

Tags: swift

I know how to rotate a UIView and also scale it and translate x and y coordinates. But I don't know how to skew it as shown in the images below.

First image is a normal red rectangle with margins of size 20px from the sides. This is the unskewed view.

[image]

Here is the desired end result rectangle. I have drawn arrows to emphasize the direction of change. Its height is larger on the right side, and lower on the left side, and it is also moved slightly towards the right, so it looks like the rectangle is being pushed into the screen from the left side.

[image]

How can I achieve this transform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a rotation in the Y-axis and adjust the [`m34`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) for your perspective:

```
// Assuming that you have a CALayer. It can be your view's layer.
// In my example this was a 100x100 square layer
let boxLayer = CALayer()

var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
let angle     = -CGFloat.pi / 8
transform.m34 = -1.0 / 500.0 // [500]: Smaller -> Closer to the 'camera', more distorted
transform     = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0, 1, 0)

boxLayer.transform = transform
```

which results to this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to animate this in such a way that it looked like the rectangle was pushed into the screen from the left side how would that look? Push and release, so animate transform, and then animate back to it's original state. How would going back look like?

Comment: Exactly as you describe it. You would set the transform for the "push" like above, animate and then animate back to the identity transform (imagine a Y rotation as any 2.5D game engine would do).

Comment: so like boxLayer.transform = .identity

Comment: That's correct. Essentially you will reset any transformations.